# Unable to use yum on RHEL 7.2

Tags: linux, yum, redhat-enterprise-linux, repository

I'm currently running RHEL Server 7.2 and every time a run a yum command (even basic things like update, install, localinstall, etc.) I receive the following error:

```
One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown), 
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
    just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
    --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

 4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel/x86_64. Please verify its path and try again
```

I read that a way to fix this was to change all the instances of "https" to "http" in /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo but this did not work for me. I also tried updating the SSL Certificates with no luck. Any thoughts? Thanks!

-Edit
This is a terminal at my school (Penn State Berks). Its one of the few linux boxes setup on campus so there is little to no support for it. It is setup for my undergrad research project so me and the professor are the only ones who ever use it. All of the network settings, including the DNS settings were configured by the school previously.

-Edit
I tried running the yum update command but with the epel repo disabled and this was the result:

```
773 physics10 -- /home/student/Desktop/tmux-x86_64-rhel6>yum update --disablerepo=epel/x86_64
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.


Error getting repository data for epel/x86_64, repository not found
774 physics10 -- /home/student/Desktop/tmux-x86_64-rhel6>yum update --disablerepo=epel
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
 http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.

One of the configured repositories failed (Nux.Ro RPMs for general desktop use),
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
    just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
    --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable nux-dextop

 4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=nux-dextop.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from nux-dextop: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on     http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on     http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on     http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on     http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on     http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on     http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on     http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on     http://mirror.li.nux.ro/li.nux.ro/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
775 physics10 -- /home/student/Desktop/tmux-x86_64-rhel6>
```

Comment: Do you have your DNS nameservers correctly configured? Can you ping `google.com` for instance?

Answer (score 1):

Hi

Do you tried to disable your epel repo which seems be the problematic repo ?

```
yum update --disablerepo=epel/x86_64
yum update --disablerepo=epel
```

If it works better, your epel configuration is wrong, may be you could delete it and reinstall it

```
rm -f /etc/yum.repos.d/epel*
yum remove epel-release
yum install epel-release
```